# Transforming String Values into a Integer Values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a function to turn string values in integers for a given column. Here is the function:

```py
def turn_to_int(value):
    if value == 'Younger than 5 years':
        return 5
    elif value == 'Older than 85':
        return 85
    else:
        pass
```

However, I get an error message whenever I try to use the map or apply function:

```
survey_strip_up = survey_strip['Age1stCode'].apply(turn_to_int)
```

These two values exist for sure, however I get this error code:

```
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-c000da272bb4> in <module>
      7         pass
      8 
----> 9 survey_strip_up = survey_strip['Age1stCode'].apply(turn_to_int)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    866         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    867         try:
--> 868             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    869 
    870             if not is_scalar(result):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4373         try:
   4374             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 4375                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   4376         except KeyError as e1:
   4377             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'Age1stCode'
```

Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Error says that `Age1stCode` column is not present in the survey_strip dataframe. Maybe you have some small Typing Mistake. Show output of `survey_strip.columns`.

Answer (score 0):

you could map a dictionary to the column. Reassign to same column name to overwrite, or (as I typically do) create a new mapped column in the same df:

```
d = {'Younger than 5 years': 5, 'Older than 85': 85}
survey_strip['new_col'] = survey_strip['Age1stCode'].map(d)
```